# Why are my images not displayed?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, xcode4, uiimage

I have a class that inherits from UIViewController lets call it 'controller' with an outlet to UICollectionView. 
a class inherited from UICollectionCell lets call it 'A' and another from UIImage lets call it 'B', A has an outlet of B

I wrote the following code in the 'controller':

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)p_collectionView    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)p_indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell* cell = [self getUICollectionViewCellFromCollectionView:p_collectionView AtIndexPath:p_indexPath];
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[ImageCollectionViewCell class]] == YES)
    {
        //draw the image inside the view
        ImageCollectionViewCell* imageCell = (ImageCollectionViewCell*)cell;
        NSString* imageUrl = self.objectToShow.imagesURL[p_indexPath.item];
        UIImage* currentImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageUrl];
        imageCell.imageView.image = currentImage;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Everything is initialized correctly but the images are not displayed, I have no clue why that is.

Comment: do you set UICollectionViewFlowLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

`initWithContentsOfFile:` expects a file path, not a `URL`. If you're using a `URL`, you should be using `initWithContentsOfURL:` which takes a `NSURL` (not a `NSString`), so you'll have to pass it `[NSURL URLWithString: imageUrl]`.

Comment: you are correct, i should change my parameter name since i am passing a file path